# Debugging problem formulation with CPLEX and PULP

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, cplex, pulp

I am currently trying to use the CPLEX Solver with PULP. The model I have defined with PULP works with the XPRESS solver, but I am having difficulties with using CPLEX.

When I run (in a jupyter notebook):

```py
path_to_cplex = '/Applications/CPLEX_Studio_Community2211/cplex/bin/x86-64_osx/cplex'
solver = CPLEX_CMD(path=path_to_cplex, msg=True)
prob.solve(solver=solver)
```

I get:

```
 Welcome to IBM(R) ILOG(R) CPLEX(R) Interactive Optimizer Community Edition 22.1.1.0
  with Simplex, Mixed Integer & Barrier Optimizers
5725-A06 5725-A29 5724-Y48 5724-Y49 5724-Y54 5724-Y55 5655-Y21
Copyright IBM Corp. 1988, 2022.  All Rights Reserved.

Type 'help' for a list of available commands.
Type 'help' followed by a command name for more
information on commands.

CPLEX> CPLEX Error  1608: Line 6: Expected '+','-' or sense, found ':'.No file read.
```

My question is how do I see what line (in this case line 6) CPLEX is referring to? I tried reading the PULP and CPLEX documentation but I couldn't find anything too helpful.

Comment: I'm usually telepathic but I seem to be having an off day. You need to post your code or this is not reproducible.

Comment: Sorry, this isn't a question about the error, this is a question about how to a see what line CPLEX is referring to in the error.

Comment: (It doesn't seem that CPLEX is referring to the lines of the problem from what pulp displays when you do something like print(prob).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this in case someone else was searching for this.

In order to see the .lp file that CPLEX is referring to, you need to pass  `keepFiles=True` when setting the solver. i.e.

```
solver = CPLEX_CMD(keepFiles=True)
prob.solve(solver=solver)
```

Then the .lp file should appear in the current directory under the name '{model_name_in_pulp}-pulp.lp'.